# Overflowing URL in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, urls

I have this entry on one of the .bib files of my Bibliography:

```
@misc{spreadsheets2,
  author = {Lima, Anderson B. E.},
  title = {Statistical Analysis of Table 3 of: "Drought Monitoring and Forecasting across Turkey: A Contemporary Review"},
  year = {2023},
  note = {Last accessed 28 July 2023},
  url = {https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSy0AU6U1roqJ3D9M5Q2mK4AvlMB8r14YeINpgHILXCGrhp_LnK9et3HRGChPic72w_DeX75rnDPh6H/pubhtml}
}
```

It overflows when printed with `\printbibliography[title=Referências]`:

[image]

How to stop the URL from overflowing?

Comment: Try to load the `xurl` package after `biblatex`.

Comment: The link you provided does not point to a bib file. Please edit your posting to show the bib entry that's giving you trouble. Do please also reveal which biblatex settings are active.

Comment: @Mico I edited the question and added the bib entry as requested. But I do not know how to reveal the biblatex settings. How to do it?

Comment: @hair-splitter I tried loading xurl before biblatex and it did not work. Now I see that it needed to be after, not before. Thank you very much. Would you like to formally provide an answer to the question?

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah - Presumably, you have an instruction such as `\usepackage[<options>]{biblatex}` somewhere in the preamble. What are the contents of the `<options>` string?

Comment: @Mico `\usepackage[natbib]{biblatex}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to load `xurl` *after* `biblatex`. And, do consider replacing the `note` field with an `urldate` field.

[image]

```
\documentclass[portuguese]{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{literatur.bib}
@misc{spreadsheets2,
  author  = {Lima, Anderson B. E.},
  title   = {Statistical Analysis of Table 3 of 
             \enquote{Drought Monitoring and Forecasting 
             across Turkey: A Contemporary Review}},
  year    = {2023},
  urldate = {2023-07-28},
  url     = {https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSy0AU6U1roqJ3D9M5Q2mK4AvlMB8r14YeINpgHILXCGrhp_LnK9et3HRGChPic72w_DeX75rnDPh6H/pubhtml}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=Referências]
\end{document}
```